# What does tomcat's ResourceCache Do? What is the difference between hitsCount and accessCount?

Tags: tomcat, monitoring

I am trying to monitor tomcat with the MBeanUtil class,I came accross the ResourceCache and its statistics.

what exactly does a resourcecache do?

I found few stats related to the Cache 1)hitsCount 2)accessCount 3) cacheSize

What does each of the above stats specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/naming/resources/ResourceCache.html) states that ResourceCache implements a special purpose cache. As its name implies it is used for caching resources that are looked up through JNDI.

From the sources I see that accessCount is incremented every time a look up is performed. hitsCount is incremented every time a resource object is returned (it is not incremented when the resource isn't found). cacheSize is the size of the cache in KB.

Comment: what kind of resources does it contain... i looked at the statistics after restarting tomcat and i observed that the hitCount is equal to the number of hits i made to the web app, i was wondering if the hitCount always returns the total number of hits??

Comment: No, it isn't the number of application hits count. It is the number of resources hits count. You could add a JNDI resource in your application to test this.